# Will I encounter problems if I install Cygwin on my SD drive?

Tags: windows-8.1, cygwin, sd-card

My computer doesn't really have much hard drive memory available (10 GB at most). It was a very cheap computer (Asus x205TA) , I bought it for  $200. It runs on Windows 8.1 32bit on a x64 processor.

I want to learn to use Linux command line. I installed the Cygwin on my C drive and installed many many packages on them. I am also learning Ruby on Rails and Git. So I don't know how exactly this happened but I used up more than 9 GB of memory. Because of this, I deleted the Cygwin directory along with all of it subdirectories and files, thinking that I could easily download and install the Cygwin and all of its packages on my SD drive instead.

So because it might take a really long time until I see if it's going to work or not, I figured I'd ask the community if you think there is going to be any problem if I install and try to run the Linux like terminal Cygwin on my SD drive (64GB).

Comment: Short answer is no, you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any issues, but haven't tried it myself.  You might want to still put `/tmp` on the hard drive to reduce wear on the SD.

Comment: I installed everything, and its all running fine except for being kinda really slow sometimes. But im guessing that it's running from an SD card. Also, i have large packages installed on cygwin, so maybe that's another thing.